# Is there an AOE Scheduler for magento 2?

Tags: cron

Or some equivalent?

It would be a great module to have for m2, no?

Comment: Doesn't AOE scheduler just show you the status of Magento cron tasks? If so you can find this information in the cron_schedule table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please have a look at these modules:

> https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/cron-scheduler-magento.html#demo

The module code can be found [here](https://github.com/wyomind/cronscheduler).

> https://github.com/shockwavemk/magento2-module-cron-schedule

I hope this would end up your search.

Comment: Wyomind extensions is also available on github: https://github.com/wyomind/cronscheduler

Comment: Thanks @mohit, does any of these extension allow creation of crons with parameters? like Aoe_scheduler do ?

Comment: @ZeeshanKhuwaja, I have not checked their settings. You can check the respective documentation of the extensions.

Answer (score 9):

This has been one of my favorite side projects: https://github.com/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager. Hopefully it helps people out!

Comment: How does this job manager work with the consumer queues in 2.2 that are defined in the Magento supplied XML files?

Comment: You'll have the ability to monitor, run, delete, disable, etc cron jobs that are registered in the consumer group. But it doesn't manage the actual message queue itself.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I really like your module. Thinking about using it on another build.

Comment: Will it work for Magento ver. 2.3.4 ?

Comment: I believe so @RahulSingh. Builds are passing: https://travis-ci.org/github/Ethan3600/magento2-CronjobManager FWIW